# How to set visibility false in LIBGDX Arraylist?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I need to set visibility false for first ladrilloOro. How can I make it happen? Below is the snippet I am trying:

```
private List<LadrilloOROEntity> LadrilloOROlist = new ArrayList<LadrilloOROEntity>();
LadrilloOROlist.set(0,LadrilloOROEntity).setVisible(false); // ERROR HERE
for (LadrilloOROEntity ladriORO : LadrilloOROlist){
        stage.addActor(ladriORO);
    }
```

Comment: Which error do you get? Is it NullPointerException?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not do it like this:

```
    LadrilloOROlist.set(0,LadrilloOROEntity); 
    LadrilloOROlist.get(0).setVisible(false);
```

Also, take a look at libGDX's 'Array' instead of using a regular ArrayList.